# Optimizer selection for Multi-Disciplinary Problems

Tags: python, optimization, openmdao

I am trying to solve the problems in [MDO Test suite](http://www.eng.buffalo.edu/Research/MODEL/newmdotestsuite.html) using OpenMDAO as a means of validation. The issue I am facing is selecting the optimizer/algorithms for a given problem.

Following is the code for the [Propane Combustion Problem](http://www.eng.buffalo.edu/Research/MODEL/test_problem_5.html) from the suite formulated through IDF method. I tried solving it using SLSQP & NSGA2 available in *pyOptSparseDriver*. But both optimizer are giving sub-optimum solution.

```
    from __future__ import print_function, division
    import numpy as np
    import time
    from openmdao.api import *

    class PropaneDis1(Component):
        def __init__(self):
            super(PropaneDis1, self).__init__()

            self.add_param('z1', 1.0)
            self.add_param('y3', np.ones(3))

            self.add_output('y1', val=np.ones(2))

        def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

            z1 = params['z1']
            y31 = params['y3'][0]

            y12 = 3.0 - z1
            y11 = z1*y31/y12

            unknowns['y1'] = np.array([y11, y12])

    class PropaneDis2(Component):
        def __init__(self):
            super(PropaneDis2, self).__init__()

            self.add_param('z1', val= 0.0)
            self.add_param('y1', val= np.ones(2))
            self.add_param('y3', val= np.ones(3))

            self.add_output('y2', val=np.ones(2))

        def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

            z1 = params['z1']
            y12 = params['y1'][1]
            y33 = params['y3'][2]

            y21 = 0.1*z1*y33/(40.0*y12)
            y22 = 0.1*(z1**2)*y33/(40.0*(y12**2))

            unknowns['y2'] = np.array([y21, y22])

    class PropaneDis3(Component):
        def __init__(self):
            super(PropaneDis3, self).__init__()

            self.add_param('z1', val=0.0)
            self.add_param('y1', val=np.ones(2))
            self.add_param('y2', val=np.ones(2))
            self.add_param('x3', val=np.ones(3))

            self.add_output('y3', val=np.ones(3))

        def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):

            z1 = params['z1']
            y11 = params['y1'][0]
            x31 = params['x3'][0]
            y12 = params['y1'][1]
            x32 = params['x3'][1]
            x33 = params['x3'][2]
            y21 = params['y2'][0]
            y22 = params['y2'][1]

            y31 = (8.0 - 2*y11 - x32 - x33)/2.0
            y32 = 4*10.0 - 2*x31
            y33 = z1 + y11 + x31 + y12 + x32 + x33 + y21 + y22 + y31 + y32

            unknowns['y3'] = np.array([y31, y32, y33])


    class PropaneIDF(Group):

        def __init__(self):
            super(PropaneIDF, self).__init__()

            self.add('pz1', IndepVarComp('z1', val=1.0), promotes=['*'])
            self.add('px3', IndepVarComp('x3', val=np.array([20.0,1.5,1.0])), promotes=['*'])
            self.add('py1t', IndepVarComp('y1t', val=np.array([1.0,1.0])), promotes=['*'])
            self.add('py2t', IndepVarComp('y2t', val=np.array([1.0,1.0])), promotes=['*'])
            self.add('py3t', IndepVarComp('y3t', val=np.array([1.0,1.0,1.0])), promotes=['*'])

            self.add('d1', PropaneDis1(), promotes=['z1', 'y1'])
            self.add('d2', PropaneDis2(), promotes=['z1', 'y2'])
            self.add('d3', PropaneDis3(), promotes=['z1', 'x3', 'y3'])

            self.connect('y1t', 'd2.y1')
            self.connect('y1t', 'd3.y1')

            self.connect('y2t', 'd3.y2')

            self.connect('y3t', 'd1.y3')
            self.connect('y3t', 'd2.y3')

            self.add('con_cmp1', ExecComp('f2=2*z1 + y1[0] + y1[1] + x3[2] + y2[0] + y3[1] + 2*y2[1] - 10.0'
                     , z1=0.0, y1=np.zeros(2), y2=np.zeros(2), y3=np.zeros(3), x3=np.zeros(3))
                     , promotes=['*'])
            self.add('con_cmp2', ExecComp('f6=abs(y1[0]*y1[1])**0.5 - x3[1]*abs(40.0*z1/y3[2])**0.5'
                     , z1=0.0, y1=np.zeros(2), y3=np.ones(3), x3=np.zeros(3))
                     , promotes=['*'])
            self.add('con_cmp3', ExecComp('f7=abs(z1*y1[0])**0.5 - x3[2]*abs(40.0*y1[1]/y3[2])**0.5'
                     , z1=0.0, y1=np.zeros(2), y3=np.ones(3), x3=np.zeros(3))
                     , promotes=['*'])
            self.add('con_cmp4', ExecComp('f9=z1*(x3[0]**0.5) - y1[1]*y3[1]*(40.0/y3[2])**0.5'
                     , z1=0.0, y1=np.zeros(2), y3=np.zeros(3), x3=np.zeros(3))
                     , promotes=['*'])

            self.add('con_cmp51', ExecComp('con51=y1t[0] - y1[0]', y1t=np.zeros(2), y1=np.zeros(2)), promotes=['*'])
            self.add('con_cmp52', ExecComp('con52=y1t[1] - y1[1]', y1t=np.zeros(2), y1=np.zeros(2)), promotes=['*'])

            self.add('con_cmp61', ExecComp('con61=y2t[0] - y2[0]', y2t=np.zeros(2), y2=np.zeros(2)), promotes=['*'])
            self.add('con_cmp62', ExecComp('con62=y2t[1] - y2[1]', y2t=np.zeros(2), y2=np.zeros(2)), promotes=['*'])

            self.add('con_cmp71', ExecComp('con71=y3t[0] - y3[0]', y3t=np.zeros(3), y3=np.zeros(3)), promotes=['*'])
            self.add('con_cmp72', ExecComp('con72=y3t[1] - y3[1]', y3t=np.zeros(3), y3=np.zeros(3)), promotes=['*'])
            self.add('con_cmp73', ExecComp('con73=y3t[2] - y3[2]', y3t=np.zeros(3), y3=np.zeros(3)), promotes=['*'])

            self.add('obj_cmp', ExecComp('obj=2*z1 + y1[0] + y1[1] + x3[2] + y2[0] + y3[1] + 2*y2[1] - 10.0 +\
                                         abs(y1[0]*y1[1])**0.5 - x3[1]*abs(40.0*z1/y3[2])**0.5+\
                                         abs(z1*y1[0])**0.5 - x3[2]*abs(40.0*y1[1]/y3[2])**0.5+\
                                         z1*(x3[0]**0.5) - y1[1]*y3[1]*(40.0/y3[2])**0.5 '
                     , z1=0.0, y1=np.zeros(2), y2=np.zeros(2), y3=np.zeros(3), x3=np.zeros(3))
                     , promotes=['*'])

            self.fd_options['force_fd']=True
            self.fd_options['step_size']=1.0e-12

    top = Problem()
    top.root = PropaneIDF()

    top.driver = pyOptSparseDriver()
    top.driver.options['optimizer']='SLSQP'

    top.driver.add_desvar('z1', lower=0.0, upper=20.0)
    top.driver.add_desvar('x3', lower=np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]), upper=np.array([20.0, 20.0, 20.0]))
    top.driver.add_desvar('y1t', lower=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), upper=np.array([20.0, 20.0]))
    top.driver.add_desvar('y2t', lower=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), upper=np.array([20.0, 20.0]))
    top.driver.add_desvar('y3t', lower=np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]), upper=np.array([20.0, 20.0, 20.0]))

    top.driver.add_objective('obj')

    top.driver.add_constraint('con51', equals=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('con52', equals=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('con61', equals=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('con62', equals=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('con71', equals=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('con72', equals=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('con73', equals=0.0)

    top.driver.add_constraint('f2', lower=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('f6', lower=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('f7', lower=0.0)
    top.driver.add_constraint('f9', lower=0.0)
    # top.driver.add_constraint('f2', equals=0.0)
    # top.driver.add_constraint('f6', equals=0.0)
    # top.driver.add_constraint('f7', equals=0.0)
    # top.driver.add_constraint('f9', equals=0.0)

    top.setup()
    tt = time.time()

    top.run()
```

Solution for SLSQP -

```
    Optimization using pyOpt_sparse
    ================================================================================

            Objective Function: _objfunc

        Solution:
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Total Time:                    0.1535
           User Objective Time :       0.0183
           User Sensitivity Time :     0.0806
           Interface Time :            0.0534
           Opt Solver Time:            0.0013
        Calls to Objective Function :      10
        Calls to Sens Function :            7

        Objectives:
            Name        Value        Optimum
            obj        14.3997             0

       Variables (c - continuous, i - integer, d - discrete):
               Name      Type       Value       Lower Bound  Upper Bound
            z1_0      c       2.130827       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
            x3_0      c      20.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
            x3_1      c       0.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
            x3_2      c      -0.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y1t_0      c       3.645641       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y1t_1      c       0.869179       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y2t_0      c       0.180723       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y2t_1      c       0.679352       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y3t_0      c       1.691004       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y3t_1      c      -0.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y3t_2      c      20.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01

       Constraints (i - inequality, e - equality):
            Name    Type                    Bounds
           con51      i        0.00e+00 <= -0.499951 <= 0.00e+00
           con52      i        0.00e+00 <= 0.000006 <= 0.00e+00
           con61      i        0.00e+00 <= 0.058146 <= 0.00e+00
           con62      i        0.00e+00 <= 0.378850 <= 0.00e+00
           con71      i        0.00e+00 <= 1.336646 <= 0.00e+00
           con72      i        0.00e+00 <= -0.000000 <= 0.00e+00
           con73      i        0.00e+00 <= -7.860081 <= 0.00e+00
             f2       i        0.00e+00 <= -0.000000 <= 1.00e+20
             f6       i        0.00e+00 <= 1.898220 <= 1.00e+20
             f7       i        0.00e+00 <= 2.972127 <= 1.00e+20
             f9       i        0.00e+00 <= 9.529347 <= 1.00e+20

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Solution for NSGA2 -

```
    Optimization using pyOpt_sparse
    ================================================================================

            Objective Function: _objfunc

        Solution:
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Total Time:                  107.5302
           User Objective Time :      62.5869
           User Sensitivity Time :     0.0000
           Interface Time :           41.6987
           Opt Solver Time:            3.2446
        Calls to Objective Function :   99981
        Calls to Sens Function :            0

        Objectives:
            Name        Value        Optimum
            obj        7.67208             0

       Variables (c - continuous, i - integer, d - discrete):
               Name      Type       Value       Lower Bound  Upper Bound
            z1_0      c       2.184051       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
            x3_0      c      20.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
            x3_1      c       0.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
            x3_2      c       0.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y1t_0      c       3.757993       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y1t_1      c       0.815949       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y2t_0      c       0.193249       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y2t_1      c       0.746901       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y3t_0      c       1.592243       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y3t_1      c      -0.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01
           y3t_2      c      20.000000       0.00e+00     2.00e+01

       Constraints (i - inequality, e - equality):
            Name    Type                    Bounds
           con51      i        0.00e+00 <= 0.173682 <= 0.00e+00
           con52      i        0.00e+00 <= -0.520903 <= 0.00e+00
           con61      i        0.00e+00 <= -0.122582 <= 0.00e+00
           con62      i        0.00e+00 <= -0.292454 <= 0.00e+00
           con71      i        0.00e+00 <= -0.120713 <= 0.00e+00
           con72      i        0.00e+00 <= 0.000372 <= 0.00e+00
           con73      i        0.00e+00 <= -7.729249 <= 0.00e+00
             f2       i        0.00e+00 <= 0.143730 <= 1.00e+20
             f6       i        0.00e+00 <= 1.641686 <= 1.00e+20
             f7       i        0.00e+00 <= 1.957046 <= 1.00e+20
             f9       i        0.00e+00 <= 3.929613 <= 1.00e+20

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know the problem isn't with the definition as I tried running the problem with the constraints f2, f6, f7 & f9 as equality constraints (=0) instead of lower bound, I am getting the optima.

So, what other optimizers should I be looking into? Or is there any other issue that I am confusing for the optimizer's problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get the details for your implementation? It does not seem to match up with the equations on the page you referenced, and I don't see any mention of a known solution either.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, looking at the SLSQP output, the optimizer was unable to deliver a feasible solution at all. Specifically, constraints con51 through con73 have numerous violations. These are the compatibility equations that replace the cyclic dependencies between your discipline components, so it seems that the optimizer was unable to converge the multidisciplinary coupling.

I have taken your code and tried a few things with it, including converting over to an MDF configuration and switching the nonlinear solver to Newton to see how it handled converging a single MDA cycle (so I also took out the optimizer). Assuming the other design variables stayed at their initial conditions, I got it to converge to a nice 1e-10 tolerance:

```
y1 [ 1.  2.]
y2 [ 0.05886036  0.02943018]
y3 [  2.          38.          47.08829054]
```

Notice that the converged value for y3 is way outside the upper bound that you specified when using y3t as a design variable under IDF:

```
top.driver.add_desvar('y3t', lower=np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
                             upper=np.array([10.0, 10.0, 10.0]))
```

I am not sure where you got the upper limits, as I didn't see them specified in the Propane problem. More importantly, I haven't been able to match up what I see in your code to what is specified in the MDO test suite link. I suspect there may be some errors, but wasn't able to verify anything.